# Searching with multiple conditions (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to search a table with multiple conditions in Rails.

I am working on deleting certain package(record) from database but first i need to get userId and packageID .

and here is the code i wrote but it gives error.

```
@package=Packages.find(:all, :condition => {:id => params[:pid]}, :condition => {:senders_id => cookies[ :user_id ]})
```

here is the error :

```
ArgumentError in CreatePackagesController#deletepackage
Unknown key: condition
```

i just need equivalent code with the right syntax to that one if someone could help.

```
def deletepackage

  @package=Packages.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => params[:pid], :senders_id => cookies[ :user_id ]}

    if (@package!=nil && req.receivedByCarrier==false)
        @package.destroy
    elsif (@package!=nil && req.receivedByCarrier==true)
        @package.destroy

end
return;
end
```

Comment: what's your rails version? `.find(:all, ...)` is deprecated in rails 4.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer? If you don't know how to accept an answer then see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235

Comment: done :) sorry for being late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query as below:

```
@package = Packages.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => params[:pid], :senders_id => cookies[:user_id]})
```

You are getting the error as `Unknown key: condition` because `:condition` is not a valid option in `find` method.

`:condition` should be `:conditions` (Note plural). Also, you should be passing both the conditions as a single key-value pair.

**For Rails 4.x**

You can simply do it as below

```
@package = Packages.where(id: params[:pid], senders_id: cookies[:user_id])
```

Comment: /home/salah/Desktop/updated/Terasoft_14/Shipme_proj/app/controllers/create_packages_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_if, expecting ')' if (@package!=nil && req.receivedByCarrier==false) ^

i will ad the full method now

Comment: I missed a round bracket. Silly me.:) I updated my answer. Try now.

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer when the timeout is over. :)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
@package=Packages.find(:all, :condition => {:id => params[:pid]}, :condition => {:senders_id => cookies[ :user_id ]})
```

should be like this

```
@package=Packages.find(:all, :conditions => {:id => params[:pid]}, :senders_id => cookies[ :user_id ]})
```